# Constantly failing to add Sherlock Action Bar to an Android project

Tags: actionbarsherlock

Following the instructional video on how to download, add and create an Android project using the Sherlock Action Bar, I'm constantly failing to add the library to the new Android project.
I followed the instructions to the letter but in the Android project's properties, under "Android", when I add the reference to the action bar, the following happens:

1. All looks fine, there's a nice green "V" sign with library's
   location under the "Reference"
2. After pressing OK and re-opening this same window, there's a red "X"
   with the file location and the "Project" row shows "?" for the
   project's name.

Again, I followed the instructions to the letter and I don't understand this issue.
If anybody has an idea... I'd appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Comment: OK. I think this has something to the way the imported library is read. would appreciate input on that and some hints.

Answer (score 0):

did you delete the android-support-v4? cause I deleted my android-support-v4 in the libs folder then error free, and if not i think ur problem is your jdk its should be jdk1.6
i used slidingmenu + abs with my project.. took me 2 days to set up... lol